# HtmlUnit Click Href "Image"

Tags: java, html, xpath, href, htmlunit

Any ideas how to click this "image" with `HtmlUnit`?

```
<a href="play.php?choose=2">
<div id="champbox" style="background-image: url(http:xxx.jpg);float:right;"></div></a>
```

Tried to click it with HtmlAnchor and Xpath, but getting errors like this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

or

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[a] attributeName=[href] attributeValue=[play.php?choose=2]
```

---

Here are all parts to reproduce the problem:

Side: http://guessleague.net/#

You don´t need a account.

My Code:

```
        //Webclient Options
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");


    // Cut out the Login (better Overview)

    HtmlAnchor anchor = page2.getAnchorByHref("play.php");
    HtmlPage page3 = anchor.click();
    System.out.println(page3.getTitleText());
    System.out.println(page3.getUrl());

    //To-Do: Click left or right Picture

    /*
    HtmlAnchor a1 = page3.getAnchorByHref("play.php?choose=2");
    System.out.println(a1.asXml());
    HtmlAnchor a2 = page3.getFirstByXPath("//a[@href='play.php?choose=2']");
    System.out.println(a2.asXml());

    a1.click();
    a2.click();
    */
    /*
    ScriptResult result = page3.executeJavaScript("vapi-client.js:41");
    result.getJavaScriptResult();
    System.out.println("result: "+ result);
    */
```

Update: And getting a new Problem with :

> checking your browser before accessing..

Try to figure this out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're talking about this, but if you want to change the cursor to show someone that you can click the image:

```
.champbox {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Not talking about this. Searching for a way to click this "image" with HtmlUnit. something like image.click(); But thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your case works with latest version/snapshot.

```html
<a href="play.php?choose=2">
  <div id="champbox" style="background-image: url(http:xxx.jpg);float:right;"></div>
</a>
```

```java
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080");
    HtmlAnchor a1 = page.getAnchorByHref("play.php?choose=2");
    System.out.println(a1.asXml());
    HtmlAnchor a2 = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@href='play.php?choose=2']");
    System.out.println(a2.asXml());
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you, i tried both ways and still getting errors:

For a better overview :  [Photo](https://www.pic-upload.de/view-32910787/Unbenannt.png.html)

Comment: Done, sorry just wanted to keep it brief and clearly